# While running Type Script code getting undefined error

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is very simple programme in type script to read value from yaml.

On running this I am getting undefined

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');
const fs = require('fs');
const cred = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('users.yml', 'utf8'));

function getUser(name:string):string { 
  return cred.name; 
} 
let v='admin'
let msg = getUser(v)  
   console.log(msg)
```

Let me know why we are getting undefined

Comment: Please do `console.log(cred)` after the `const cred = ...` and post here whats the content of `cred`.

Comment: @vicbyte when I do console.log(cred) I am getting following result from yaml file as    { admin:
   { username: 'Administrator',
     password: 'abc123',
     newPassword: 'abc' }}

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to access a property with a name that is a variable, so you should do:

```
function getUser(name:string):string { 
  return cred[name];
}
```